# How to get the div block to be centered in a modal window

Tags: css, html

I am a NOOB with css and am trying to construct a modal that will hold a video. I want the div that will hold the video to be placed in the center of the screen.

However, I'm having some trouble positioning it. I must be misunderstanding how this positioning works. It seems incorrect to have to use bottom: 1700px.

I want the user to be able to move the box up and down by scrolling in case their screen is too small.

How can center this div in the screen correctly?

HTML:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div id="videoModal" class="modalContainer">
    <div class="videoOverlay"></div>
    <div class="videoContainer">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*-------------------------*/
/* ----- Video Modal ----- */
/*-------------------------*/

<!-- language: lang-css -->
.modalContainer {
    display: none;
}

.modalContainer.open {
    display: inherit;
}

.videoOverlay {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:100;
}

.videoContainer {
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1700px;
    left: 25%;
}
```

JS:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$('#openVideoModal').click(function(){
    $('.modalContainer').addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to position `.videoContainer` at the center of the screen, you can do the following:

```
.videoContainer {
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 200;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: This works for the width. For the height the videoContainer is still too high on the page.  Setting top:63% works. I just don't understand where to position:relative to make this work correctly.

Comment: Have you removed the `bottom: 1700px;` from the style? And you put `position:relative` on the parent div of `.videoContainer` in which you want the position to be relative to (If you don't put `position:relative` then it will be relative the the body

Comment: Thanks Alon. I fixed it as you said, by putting position:relative on a parent container in the section I want the modal to show.  Now the code you suggested works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your videoContainer:

```
.videoContainer {
   background-color: white;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   z-index: 200;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: 250px;
   left: 25%;
}
```

Basically, you set your block at 50% from the top of your page with a negative margin of half your height value.
Same for horizontal values.

Comment: I tried this. The problem I seem to have is where to put position:relative. I think its using the body currently.